# How to find any higher than 0 number in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write code to help me find any numbers greater than 0 in a column and show me the result, number by number, in a message box.

```
Dim n
n = 1

Do Until Cells(n + 1, 1) = ""
    n = n + 1
    If Cells(n, 17).Value > 0 Then
        MsgBox Cells(n, 17).Value
    End If
Loop
```

It should show me a message box at least three times (based on the data sheet I'm working on right now) but I've got nothing!

Comment: Seen like this, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. The issue should be looked in the dataset you're working with, I think. You're most probably not reading the good column number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Show Positive Number in Column

The problem of your code might be in the fact that you are 'doing' until a "" occurs in column **A**, but you are showing the values of column **Q**, e.g. if **A2** isn't greater than 0, there will be no message boxes.

### For Next Version

```
Sub ShowPositive()

    Const cSheet As Variant = "Sheet1"  ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cFirstR As Integer = 1        ' First Row Number
    Const cColumn As Variant = 17       ' Column Letter/Number e.g. "Q" or 17

    Dim lastR As Long   ' Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long       ' Row Counter

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        ' Calculate Last Row Number.
        lastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Loop through all rows.
        For i = cFirstR To LastR
            ' Check if current cell contains a number AND
            ' if it is greater than 0.
            If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, cColumn)) And .Cells(i, cColumn) > 0 _
                    Then MsgBox .Cells(i, cColumn)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

### Do Loop Version

```
Sub ShowPositive2()

    Const cSheet As Variant = "Sheet1"  ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cFirstR As Integer = 1        ' First Row Number
    Const cColumn As Variant = 17       ' Column Letter/Number e.g. "Q" or 17

    Dim n As Long       ' Row Counter

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)

        n = cFirstR ' To skip First Row.
        Do Until .Cells(n + 1, cColumn) = ""
            n = n + 1
            If IsNumeric(.Cells(n, cColumn)) And .Cells(n, cColumn) > 0 _
                Then MsgBox .Cells(n, cColumn)
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean `For i = cFirstR To lastR` ?

Comment: Thank you for your replay, actually I want the code to go over column Q, until it reach to a "" in column A.

Comment: any way, your code really worked as I wanted it. Thanks a lot.